# ListView scroll issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, scroll

I've got `ListView` with custom row item. My item has a button and when I clicked it, then in this row dynamically is adding new button. My problem is when I scroll list. Dynamically added button showing in wrong rows. It's issue with reusing view but i don't know how to remember state of row. Please help me. This is my adapter, method getView.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    final int positionRow = position;
    model = values.get(position);

    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(rowView);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
    }else
    {

        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        ((ViewHolder) rowView.getTag()).mPortionButton.setTag(model);

    }

    if(values == null || ((position + 1)> values.size()) )
        return rowView;


    final int[] portionCounter = {1};
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View counterButton = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.button_counter, null);
    Button counterB = (Button) counterButton.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    counterB.setTypeface(MainActivity.font);
    final LinearLayout[] layout = {(LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.portionLayout)};


    holder.mPortionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (portionCounter[0] == 1) {
                layout[0].addView(counterButton);
                ++portionCounter[0];
            }
            else {
                TextView counter = (TextView) counterButton.findViewById(R.id.textOne);
                counter.setText(String.valueOf(portionCounter[0]));
                ++portionCounter[0];
            }

        }
    });



    holder.mProduct.setText(model.getName());

    holder.mBrand.setText(model.getBrand());
    if (model.getProductThumb()!=null && model.getProductThumb().trim().length() > 0){
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(model.getProductThumb())
                .into(holder.mProductIcon);
    }
    else{
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(R.drawable.temp_icon)
                .into(holder.mProductIcon);
    }


    return rowView;
}
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: keep it in model variable (model = values.get(position);)

Comment: I'm working right now on it. I've got counter for clicked button which   I show in dynamically added View, should I save it too?

Comment: yes, you should save cnt too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have model so just use it. Your model have to remember when button was added and later when method `getView` is called you have to get previously saved state of row. Sample:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    model = values.get(position);
    ViewGroup rowContainer = (ViewGroup) convertView;

    View button = convertView.getChildAt(0);//get already added button (if it was). getChildAt method is example. It depends on your layout.

    if(model.isButtonAdded()){
        if(button == null){//button was not added before then you shoul add it
            rowContainer.addView(new Button());
        }
    }else{
        if(button != null){//button exists, you should remove it
            rowContainer.removeChild(button);
        }
    }
}
```